# Simultaneous equations and separate labels

Tags: labels, cases

Essentially I'm trying to obtain something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31951/separate-labels-in-cases) (without the `f(x)` bit), but with custom labels, which I can't seem to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x+y &= 3 &&& \text{5} \\
x-y &= 1 &&& \text{6} \\
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

But it just doesn't work.

I additionally tried the `numcases` solution in the link, but it seems like I can't manually `tag` it.

Here is my attempt with the `empheq` package:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,empheq}
\usepackage{cases}
\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}{align*} 
\begin{cases}
x+y &= 3 \tag{5} \\
x-y &= 1 \tag{6}
\end{cases}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

The problem over here is that it shows only a `(5)` next to both the equations somewhere vertically in the center, not a `(5)` for one equation and a `(6)` for the other ;P

Comment: See [How can you number equations manually?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212559/how-can-you-number-equations-manually).

Comment: @gernot Unfortunately, I can't use `tag` in a `numcases` environment it seems....

Comment: Is the left-hand curly brace essential?

Comment: @Mico well, I really wanted it :) that's the reason I'm asking!

Comment: See empheq, AFAIR you can overwrite the eqn no using tag in that construction

Comment: @daleif thanks for the suggestion, but I can't see anything that's related to tags… sorry, I'm quite new to this language

Comment: There is an example in the manual for that package that gives you a cases-like output with eqn numbers. Try to copy that example, when it works try overwriting the eqn number using `\tag`, I'm not at a pc so cannot do it for you.

Comment: does this help: [Separate labels in `cases`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31951)?  it's possible to have nothing on the left preceding the brace; just leave the first argument empty `{}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton This doesn't seem to give me manual tags

Comment: @daleif Okay, I just tried that suggestion and it seems to give a custom tag, but it doesn't look like I can tag both equations in the braces. Thanks anyway for helping!

Comment: Why not? Please update your question with the code you have now

Comment: @daleif Hey, I did it, but someone already answered it for me giving me an alternate way of doing it. So you don't need to look at my question. But thank you very, very much for trying to help.

Comment: That is not how the example goes in the manual. Remove the inner cases, and add the left brace via the extra optional option to empheq

Comment: See the example code at the bottom of page 7 (result is on page 8), remove the right part. Note that tag overwrites also in non-starred align.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{4}
\begin{numcases}{}
 x+y = 3 \\
 x-y = 1
\end{numcases}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

this is exactly what is provided by the examples in this question:
[Separate labels in `cases`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31951),
which is why i suggested it as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm sorry! I was playing around with the examples but I didn't get anywhere. I had no idea about the `setcounter` command! I also searched for it on that page, but couldn't see it there...

Comment: I'd like to add the reason I was completely clueless about this. I never used the `equation` environment because I write in MathJax with `$$` and use `pandoc` to convert it over (which is far from perfect), and I always used the `tag` command to number my equations, so I never had "official" equation counters anyway! That's why nothing was working for me. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: @SkeletonBow -- your confusion is understandable, given your method of preparing input.  however, it would have made the question more understandable if you'd included the information about that method in the question.