# An equation with Feyman diagrams inside

Tags: equations, tikz-feynman, feynman

[image]

I want to include this equation number 6.87 and 6.88 as same as in the screenshot to my project, please give some help to do this...

Comment: Does this help? https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/feynman_diagrams

Comment: No, the things are so big, not able to use it inside equations @Alan Xiang

Comment: Can you please give an answer@Alan Xiang

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know anything about Feyman diagrams, which means I am unable to recreate these symbols. However, if you are able to provide some sample code for Feyman diagrams, I think I do know how to adjust their size for equations.

Comment: You can use [\resizebox](https://latexref.xyz/_005cresizebox.html) to change the size of an object.

Comment: Can they align perfectly as shown in the above screenshot?@ Alan Xiang

Comment: Can you please help@Bernard

Comment: If you can provide an example of existing Feynman diagram in LaTeX, maybe I can test whether the alignment is OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm an absolutely sporadic user of Ti*k*Z and I have no experience whatsoever in drawing Feynman diagrams with it (I still use `feynmp` for that...) but here's a shot at it

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% \tikz picture vertically centered on math axis
\newcommand*{\ctikz}[2][]{\hbox{\mathsurround=3pt$\vcenter{\hbox{\tikz[#1]{#2}}}$}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\newcommand*{\I}{\mathrm{i}}

\begin{document}

\[
Z[j] =
\frac{\displaystyle \biggl[ 1 - \frac{\I\,g}{4!} \int 
      \biggl(
      -3 \ctikz{ \draw(0,0)circle(0.2); \draw(0.4,0)circle(0.2); }
      + 6\I
        \ctikz{
          \draw[{Rays[]}-{Rays[]}](0,0)--(0.8,0);
          \draw(0.4,0.2)circle(0.2);}
      + \ctikz{
          \draw[{Rays[]}-{Rays[]}](0.3,0.3)--(-0.3,-0.3);
          \draw[{Rays[]}-{Rays[]}](-0.3,0.3)--(0.3,-0.3);}
      \biggr)
      \exp\biggl(-\frac{\I}{2} \int J \Delta_{\mathrm{F}} J \biggr)\biggr] \mathrm{d}z}% end of numerator
     {\displaystyle 1 - \frac{\I\,g}{4!} \int \Bigl(-3 \ctikz{\draw(0,0)circle(0.2);\draw(0.4,0)circle(0.2);}\Bigr) \mathrm{d}z}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, Thanks, Can I am unable to number this equation, can you tell me how to do it? @campa

Comment: @ROBINRAJ Use the `equation` environment. Or give a look at [How can you number equations manually?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/212559/82917)

Comment: I tried using \label and \eqref, but not works in this case@campa

Comment: @ROBINRAJ Sorry but I can't read minds. If you have another problem then please [ask a new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).