# Feynman diagrams inside equation environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman, feynmf, feynmp-auto

I need to type the expression below[image]
I am thinking of using `tikzpicture` inside the `eqnarray` environment. Although I am not quite sure which way would be the best to get this done. Can someone please give some feedback on this? Thanks!

Comment: [Don't use `eqnarray`.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196) Have you seen [the `tikz-feynman` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)? The [tag:tikz-feynman] has a few examples. Though, I see only three kinds of diagrams so those could just simply be drawn with bare TikZ as well.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557365/an-equation-with-feyman-diagrams-inside

Comment: You can see my attempt at something similar in my [QFT notes](https://github.com/WilloughbySeago/Uni-Notes/tree/main/year-5/Quantum-Field-Theory), for example, on page 208 of the pdf, line 8974 of the tex file, it basically proceeds as you suggest, but just with the `equation` environment since it fits on one line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For these simple diagrams the `tikz-feynman` package might be a bit overkill.

You only have three types of diagrams with a variance of nodes:

- `.` no node,
- `o` white with border,
- `*` filled and, maybe,
- `+` for the diamond shaped at the bottom of the loop.

All three have possibily one label at always the same place.

With a few styles these can achieved with plain TikZ.

`amsmath`'s `\text` macro helps scale font-sizes in superscripts, this avoids implementing our own `\mathchoice`r as long as we define lengths in terms of font dependent units (em and ex, see the definition of `every diagram`).

The third argment (i.e. the second mandatory one) in each command is the content of the label.
The second one describes the list of nodes. For the line diagram these need to contain two tokens, for the loop three and for the cross five.
They describe the nodes from left to right from top to bottom.

That means that

```
\tfCross{.+o*o}{X}
```

leads to
[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\p()
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\brak[]
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
  feynman/.cd,
  every diagram/.style={x=+1.3em, y=+1.3em, baseline=+-.5ex},
  label/.style={anchor=north west,inner sep=+.2em, scale=.707,
    node font=\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\scriptstyle}},
  node/.style={shape=circle, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+2pt, node contents=},
  node ./.style={feynman/node, shape=coordinate},
  node o/.style={feynman/node, fill=white, draw},
  node */.style={feynman/node, fill,       draw},
  node +/.style={
    feynman/node, fill, draw, shape=rectangle, rotate=45, minimum size=+1pt},
  loop/.style n args={4}{insert path={
      (0,0) node[feynman/label]{$#4$} node[feynman/node #1] -- ++(right:1)
      arc[start angle=-90, delta angle=360, radius=.5] node[feynman/node #2]
      -- ++(right:1) node[feynman/node #3]}},
  cross diagram/.style={
    /tikz/feynman/label/.append style={anchor=south east, inner sep=+.2pt}},
  cross/.style n args={6}{insert path={
    (225:.707) node[feynman/label]{$#6$} node[feynman/node #4]
    -- (45:.707) node[midway,feynman/node #3] node[feynman/node #2]
    (135:.707) node[feynman/node #1] -- (-45:.707) node[feynman/node #5]}},
  line/.style n args={3}{insert path={
    (0,0) node[feynman/label]{$#3$} node[feynman/node #1]
    -- (right:.8) node[feynman/node #2]}}}
\newcommand*\tfInt[4]{%
  \text{\tikz[feynman/every diagram,feynman/#1 diagram/.try,#2]
    \draw[feynman/#1={#3{#4}}];}}
\newcommand*\tfLoop[1][]{\tfInt{loop}{#1}}
\newcommand*\tfCross[1][]{\tfInt{cross}{#1}}
\newcommand*\tfLine[1][]{\tfInt{line}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
\frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\delta}{\delta J(x_1)} W\brak J
 = \frac{\hbar}{i} \frac{\delta}{\delta J(x_1)}
     \brak[\bigg]{1+\frac{g}{4!}
       \p[\bigg] { 6             \,\tfLoop{o+o}{x_1} +     \tfCross{oo*oo}{} }}
     e^{\frac 12 \tfLine{oo}{}} \\
 = \brak[\bigg]{
     \frac{g}{4!}
       \p[\bigg] {     6 \cdot 2 \,\tfLoop{.+o}{x_1} + 4 \,\tfCross{oo*.o}{x_1}}
     + \p[\bigg] {1 + \frac{g}{4!}
                     \p[\bigg]{6 \,\tfLoop{o+o}{x_1} +     \tfCross{oo*oo}{}}}
     \tfLine{.*}{x_1}
    } e^{\frac 12 \tfLine{oo}{}} \\
 = \brak[\bigg]{
     \tfLine{.o}{x_1} + \frac{g}{4!} \p[\bigg]{
       12 \,\tfLoop{.+o}{x_1} + 4 \,\tfCross{oo*.o}{x_1}
      + 6 \,\tfLoop{o+o}{} \, \tfLine{.*}{x_1}
      + \tfCross{oo*oo}{} \, \tfLine{.*}{x_1}
     }
   } e^{\frac 12 \tfLine{oo}{}}
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: @rrbrbirlbel, Thanks for your answer. How can one add a diagram with two circles touching each other, (link: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/295607/feynman-diagrams-for-phi4-theory-up-to-order-g2). Also, is there any way to make circles and the internal lines thick?

Comment: @felix If you want only the lines thicker but not the nodes, you can add `thick` to the `every diagram` style and `thin` (the default) to the `node` style. My solution is still rather inflexible. I suggest to create a new style for this. (We might be able to create a `\tfLoop` macro that adds another loop and node based on a key but it gets complicated parsing the whole thing.)